# How to setup port redirection after a ssh connection has been opened?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, port-forwarding

I'm using openssh on both client and server. I know I can run `ssh -L` or `ssh -R` to setup some port redirections over ssh. However, since they are command-line parameters, such redirections must be written before the connection is opened.

**Can I setup port redirections on-the-fly using the command-line ssh client?**

When I used the `PuTTY` ssh client, I could interactively setup a port redirection while a connection was already opened, without dropping nor reconnecting, thus I know it is technically possible.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're using the SSH command line, and you haven't switched the [escape character](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1&format=html#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS) feature off, then you can type `~C` after a newline to open a mini-console on the ssh client. Then type `-L port:host:port` or `-R port:host:port` or `-D port` as you would on the command line to add a redirection, or `-KR port` to remove a redirection.

A more flexible method to set up redirections without redoing the authentication is to start the first ssh client as a master (`-M` or `-o ControlMaster=auto`) and subsequent clients as slaves (`-S` or `-o ControlMaster=auto`). The slaves tunnel through the connection established by the master. You may need to set `ControlPath` on the command line or in your `~/.ssh/config`; see the description of the options in the [`ssh_config` man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) for more information.

Comment: In case anyone runs into the `~C escape not available to multiplexex sessions` problem as I did just now, don't go hunting for your master connection. Instead, just add `-O forward` to your ssh port forwarding command, as in `ssh -O forward -nfL 1234:whatever:1234 theserver` and it'll work.

Comment: Note that Enter must be pressed prior to the escape sequence. The Enter key gets forwarded to the host, so don’t do it with a half-entered command in limbo. On the other hand, if you have just launched a command by pressing Enter, you can proceed straight to the `~C` sequence.