# Add port forwarding to a running SSH session

Tags: openssh, port-forwarding

The OpenSSH client has a command line option for port forwarding, used like this:

```
ssh -L localport:server:serverport user@host
```

which will connect to `host` as `user`, and at the same time redirecting `localport` on the client to `serverport` on `server` (which can be `host` or anything reachable from `host` over the network).

Now suppose I have SSHed into `host` doing just

```
ssh user@host
```

and in the middle of the session I realize I forgot to forward the port. Alas, I am in the middle of something, so I don’t just want to log out and re-establish the SSH connection with the port forwarding.

Is there a way to add port forwarding to a running SSH session?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup port redirection after a ssh connection has been opened?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30515/how-to-setup-port-redirection-after-a-ssh-connection-has-been-opened)

Comment: In principle, yes. However, the instruction is missing the part that one needs to press Enter first. With that answer alone, I would not have figured out how to get to the SSH console.

Comment: "type ... *after a newline*"

Comment: You’re right... after reading the answer for the third time I finally spotted the relevant part.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS):

> ESCAPE CHARACTERS
>
> When a pseudo-terminal has been requested, ssh supports a number of functions through the use of an escape character.
>
> A single tilde character can be sent as `~~` or by following the tilde by a character other than those described below. The escape character must always follow a newline to be interpreted as special. The escape character can be changed in configuration files using the `EscapeChar` configuration directive or on the command line by the `-e` option.
>
> The supported escapes (assuming the default `~`) are:
>
> […]
>
> `~C`
> Open command line. Currently this allows the addition of port forwardings using the `-L`, `-R` and `-D` options (see above). […] Basic help is available, using the -h option.

So type <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>`~`</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (i.e. *capital* c), then

```
-L localport:server:serverport
```

with desired `localport`, `server` and `serverport`, finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Notes:

- The initial <kbd>Enter</kbd> will be immediately sent to the remote side and may cause some action there, so pick a good moment (e.g. when you're in a shell with an empty command line). Or *if you are sure* the last thing you have typed is <kbd>Enter</kbd> anyway (e.g. you have just invoked a command that is now running), you can start directly with <kbd>`~`</kbd> because <kbd>Enter</kbd> has already been noticed by your local `ssh`.
- On internationalized keyboards the tilde could be a dead key for generating special 'tilded' characters (like pressing <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to generate `ñ`). In that case, it could be necessary to press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> after <kbd>~</kbd> to generate a single tilde, i.e: <kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. In the case of the Spanish/LA keyboard layouts, as there is no combined character using tilde and C, the space can be omitted and the <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> generates the desired sequence.
- Regarding multiple redirections, the `ssh` escaped command line only accepts a single command. You should press again the keyboard sequence to enter another command or redirection.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/1192862/570332 (*SSH escape key ("~") only works when connection is stuck?... Simple workaround*...)

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple ssh connections. Port forwarding can be performed independently of your running connection. Further, it has to be performed on the client side for `-L`.

You can add `-N -f` to your command to background it from another terminal window and not send any <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This backgrounding may not properly work in Windows, just minimise the terminal.

Yes, there is [another answer covering <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697834/377345).