# Why does ssh port forwarding fail?

Tags: ssh, openssh, port-forwarding

In this example:

```
$ ssh -L 8001:192.168.122.4:80
```

the output give is the default help:

```
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

What could be the reason(s)?

Comment: The command is incomplete, try adding the remote host at least (if username is the the same on both systems).

Comment: But there's already an active session; this runs into an ssh-ed into machine

Comment: "this runs into an ssh-ed into machine" – Do you want to [add port forwarding to a running SSH session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697825/108618)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is incomplete. As you can see in the usage page, the only mandatory argument is `destination` and you have not specified it.

`-L 8001:192.168.122.4:80` is a parameter but it is not the destination.

Each `ssh` connection is independent, you really need to provide, for each one, at the very least, a `destination`. That's why you get the usage information.

Try something like this:

```
$ ssh -L 8001:192.168.122.4:80 destination
```